# Custom widgets are not showing in the cq:dialog for touch ui

Tags: dialog, widget, aem, custom-widgets

Hi I am working on touch ui, and converting the dialogs (page properties, dialog etc) into cq:dialog, normal cq widgets are getting converted automatically using the convertor tool.

We have many custom widgets which we are calling in the dialogs for configuring various page specific properties, these custom widgets are not showing up in the page properties dialog in touch ui mode whereas showing up in normal mode.

Can anyone give any pointers to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom widgets created in Classic UI and need support for same in Touch UI, then simple answer is to create those Custom Widgets for Touch UI. Though Touch UI widget library is extensive, so look into library to see if any existing widget will match your requirement in touch ui.